# Levy Metric in Probability Distribution Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces

I have a two functionals $f(F_X)$ and $g(F_X)$ defined as
\begin{align}
f&: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+\\
g&: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}
where $F_X(x)\in \Omega$, is the probability distribution function of some non-negative discrete random variable. Now, consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation}
\max_{F_X\in\Omega} \alpha f(F_X) + (1-\alpha) g(F_X), \, \alpha\in [0,1].
\end{equation}
We have the following assumptions:

a) $f(F_X)$ and $g(F_X)$ are both continuous in $F_X$ in the Levy metric sense; b) the objective function is strictly concave in $F_X$; c) for all values of $\alpha\in(0,1]$, $F_X^*$ (the maximizer) has an infinite number of mass points. I would like to prove that this property (having an infinite number of mass points) is also valid when $\alpha = 0$ using the continuity assumption.

Here are my attempts so far: I have proceeded by a contradiction argument, i.e., I have assumed that $F_X^{*}(x)$ corresponding to $\alpha = 0$ has finite number of mass points. Then for an $\alpha$ which is arbitrarily close to $0$, the corresponding maximizer $G_X^*(x)$ also must have a finite number of mass points because, as $\alpha\rightarrow 0^+ \Rightarrow L(F_X^*,G_X^*)\rightarrow 0$ due to continuity, where
\begin{equation}
L(F_X^*,G_X^*) := \inf\lbrace \epsilon > 0 \mid F_X^*(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon \leq G_X^*(x) \leq F_X^*(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+ \rbrace.
\end{equation}
is the Levy metric.
We observe that for all $x$ that are not in the support set of $F_X^*(x)$, $G_X^*(x)$ must be arbitrarily close to 1, i.e., the support set of the $G_X^*$ must also be finite, which is a contradiction as $G_X^*(x)$ has an infinite number of mass points.

My question is that is this proof sound? If yes, any suggestion on how to be more specific. If not, why?